# Slide Menu using Fragments: How to don't return on Splashscreen on back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I just implemented this menu, but the difference it's I'm gonna use some Actitivies at the beginning,for splascreen and sign-in:

```
public class SpashscreenActivity  extends FragmentActivity {
    DatabaseHandler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Splashscreen code...

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        if (db.checkForTables() == false) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, InscriptionActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ACCUEIL"));
        }

    }
}
```

If the check of the table user is empty, I'm gonna show the activity for sign-in:

```
public class InscriptionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //form...



                        db.addUtilisateur(new Utilisateurs(pseudo,indicecalorique,age,genre,taille,tauxmassegrasse,frequenceactivite));


                        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ACCUEIL"));
}
}
```

Sowhen I'm in the Fragment with the Slide menu and I push on back button, the previous activity is opening, but I won't to get it back, how to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple..when you are moving activity using intent, just write **finish();** like this.

```
if (db.checkForTables() == false) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, InscriptionActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ACCUEIL"));
            finish();
        }
  }
```

it will destroy your activity so you wont get back on back button.

or you can used in the current activity

```
@ovveride
onPause(){
 super.onPause();
 finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a question, how to quit the app, only if we are in a specify fragment on back bouton, and go in this one when we are in an another activity, for exemple I wan't to gat back to home everytime and if i'm at home or already at I want to quit the app on back button

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
if (db.checkForTables() == false) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InscriptionActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ACCUEIL"));
        finish();
    }
  }
```